# HTML form radio conditional

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, conditional-statements, radio-button

¡Hello! I need to make this range start working when the check is pressed ¿Can I get some help? Thanks

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<input type="checkbox" id="si" name="nivel" onclick="myFunction()"><label for="si">Si</label> 

<input type="range"id="tickmarks" disabled="disabled" />
<datalist id="tickmarks">
<option value="bajo" label="Bajo"></option>
<option value="medio" label="Medio"></option>
<option value="alto" label="Alto"></option>
</datalist>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var nivel = document.getElementById("si");
  var tickmarks = document.getElementById("tickmarks");
  if (nivel.checked == true){
    tickmarks.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     tickmarks.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

I tried to press the checkbox to make the range appear and it could be selected but when it appears it is disabled.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. You are also inconsistent in its usage. One time you use it and another time you don't.

Comment: As a sidenote, `tickmarks` is not a unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control whether an element is disabled by setting the element's `disabled` attribute to `true`/`false`.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="si" name="nivel" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="range" id="tickmarks" disabled>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    const nivel = document.getElementById("si");
    const tickmarks = document.getElementById("tickmarks");
    if (nivel.checked == true) {
        tickmarks.disabled = false;
    } else {
        tickmarks.disabled = true;
    }
}
```